# Pinata Parties won't work

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

It's been awhile since pinata parties have stopped showing up. I have IOS 7.1 (jail'd) and Im always online on my WiFi. I receive notifications for pinata parties but when I start pvz2 its not there. Also most of the time, PvZ2 nvr loads when I'm on wifi. Any way to fix these issues?

Comment: It's probably because your iOS device is jailbroken.

Comment: Because when I play, it works completely fine.

Comment: I *sincerely* doubt it has anything to do with a jailbroken device.

Comment: It's not because of jailbreak